# Equivalent of "~\nameoffile.file" in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, single-page-application

Using Blazor to make a SPA. I have a file that's going to be at the root, so how can I access it in a consistent manner?

```
static string JSONPathDev = @"C:\Projects\pdc-classroom-display\externalKeys.properties";
static string JSONPathProduction1 = @"C:\inetPub\PDCDisplay\externalKeys.properties";
```

I'm currently just changing this variable depending on where the program is running. So, what's the equivalent of "~/file.txt" in asp.net? Do I need a controller?

Comment: Its a good idea to specify Blazor Server or Blazor WASM.

Answer (score 0):

Blazor is server side, you should be able to use relative paths

Ensure you inject HttpClient, then do:

var data = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync("/externalKeys.properties");